# Can muparser parse a function with different definitions over different domains?

Tags: c++, parsing, equation

I have the following function f(x):

```
f(x) = fun1(x)  if x<a
f(x) = fun2(x)  if a<=x and if x<b
f(x) = fun3(x)  if b<=x
```

Is there a syntax such that I can write this function into a string such thatit  will be understood by muparser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

muParser understands the `?:` operator, as in C/C++ and other derivatives. So you could write the body of `f(x)` as:

```
x<a ? fun1(x) : x<b ? fun2(x) : fun3(x)
```

I'm not sure if that really captures what you want, but it will work because `?:` short-circuits (so that the first `:` implicitly includes the condition `!(x<a)` )